# Wordpress: query_posts - how to show multiple posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm building a custom WP theme (based on Chris Coyier's tutorial at lynda.com) that displays a snip of the most recent blog post on the home page (the blog itself is not the homepage of the site). I'm currently showing just one post, but would like to have the option to show two or more posts. Here's the current code:

```
   <?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1"); the_post(); ?>
   <div class="date_home">Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
   <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
   <?php the_content('Continue Reading &#8594;'); ?>
```

I would have thought that changing

`posts_per_page=1`

to

`posts_per_page=2`

would do the the trick, but it's not working.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Need to replace:
`<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1"); the_post(); ?>`

with:
`<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=5'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>`

Complete Code below:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=5');  
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
<div class="date_home">Posted <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></div>
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
<?php the_content('Continue Reading &#8594;'); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Your original code did not account for multiple posts by running it through the loop. This is where the if / while comes it. 'if' checks for the posts and 'while' tells it what to do 'while' it still has posts posts to run though. Arguments are passed to the query in the query_posts(); as you had in your original code.

Comment: Glad I could help @dadra, be sure to close / accept your question as 'Answered'